# Reusable scope in windows firewall

Tags: windows-firewall

Windows firewall has the concept of scope wherein a scope can be a list of IP blocks, or a predefined "set" (e.g.: localsubnet, gateway, WINS, etc.)

Is there a way to modify and/or create a custom "set" which can be reused in multiple rules and edited again later?

I'm trying to akin to a "table" that you can do in other firewalls.